# brunel visualization - Javascript error on ploting line chart

Tags: javascript, python, dataframe

I'm trying to plot a line chart and here is the imported data from csv file:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import brunel
import re

# Read data
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
DISKAVGRIO = pd.read_csv("../DISKAVGRIO_nmon.csv", parse_dates=['DateTime'], date_parser=dateparse)

DISKAVGRIO.head(6)
# Select all column names that starts with hdisk
hdisks = [col for col in DISKAVGRIO.columns if 'hdisk' in col]
yaxis = 'y(' + ','.join(hdisks) + ')'
#print(list(DISKAVGRIO.columns))
print(yaxis)
# Line plot
%brunel data('DISKAVGRIO') x(DateTime) $yaxis line
```

But when I try to plot the line chart I get the following error message:

```
Javascript error adding output!
SyntaxError: "0"-prefixed octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated; for octal literals use the "0o" prefix instead
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Or what is missing?

Comment: have you checked your console for more details, per the message?

Comment: Has this information but I don't know what it means:
SyntaxError: "0"-prefixed octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated; for octal literals use the "0o" prefix instead
...
Doesn't fit the stack trace.